# how to change a property type in a class that has made .dll

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mecmd.jpg)I develop a program that needs a scheduler component 
 and this component no have Persian date-time, now I want to create a 
property in this .dll that has Persian DateTime...
 do I overRide this .dll?

Comment: please explain more about what you've done until now and what you want to do with your code now.

Comment: hi, thanks your replay, please see an image in my description, I have edited my question recently

Answer (score 1):

If it was `virtual` you could `override` it. In this situation, you can use `Extension methods` like this:

```
public static class YourClass
{
    public static string GetPersianDate(this dll.Class param)
    {
        // Do your business
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Look at my example.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string GetPersianDate(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pc.GetYear(dateTime), pc.GetMonth(dateTime), pc.GetDayOfMonth(dateTime));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks your replay, please see an image in my description, I have edited my question recently